# Python SpeechRecognition running but not hearing through the mic

Tags: python, speech-recognition, pyaudio

So I'm trying to use python SpeechRecognition 1.1.3 but it is not recognizing me through my mic. I've installed pyAudio and everything seems to be working smoothly when I run the example code provided by SpeechRecognition:

```
# NOTE: this requires PyAudio because it uses the Microphone class
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:                # use the default microphone as the audio source
    audio = r.listen(source)                   # listen for the first phrase and extract it into audio data

try:
    print("You said " + r.recognize(audio))    # recognize speech using Google Speech Recognition
except LookupError:                            # speech is unintelligible
    print("Could not understand audio")
```

It just sits waiting to hear an input from the mic. The mic works and SpeechRecognition is able to recognize that it is the default mic because when I unplug it the code barfs. Any suggestions?

I am running python 2.7.6 and my OS is Windows 7.  Additionally, I've got all of this on an E: drive just to make life a little more complicated... :/

Comment: Have you checked if your microphone is muted?

Comment: It was not muted. I checked my recording devices and saw it react whenever I talked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the script, Pyaudio hasn't been installed. Don't worry, this is a common syntax error an application could receive. What I recommend you doing is you have to reinstall your Python program to the version that will be able to run under the **Pyaudio 1.1.3.** You haven't specified what version of Python you're using and what OS is your computer operating under (i.e. Windows Vista, 7 or 8). Supposing that you might be using either Windows 8 or 7, you have to type in *easy_install* in the windows cmd. Yet, if that won't work, install this Python script: `http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py` Then reattempt the process by typing in *easy_install* from `C:\<Your python directory>\Scripts\`. Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the similar kind of problem then I realized that it was the internet connection problem. Check the Broadband connection speed or test via cellular network connection.